# Trying to forward an HTTPS URL to another

Tags: https, redirect, 301-redirect

The domain ultimateedgeapparel.com is registered on GoDaddy and I've setup a 301 redirect through GoDaddy's forwarding service to this page - https://www.allvolleyball.com/ultimate-edge which works.

But if someone tries to visit https://ultimateedgeapparel.com, the connection times out.

Currently, ultimateedgeapparel.com is using the default nameservers for GoDaddy. I'm just trying figure out the best way to redirect any requests for ultimateedgeapparel.com to the page mentioned above.

Comment: `ultimateedgeapparel.com` resolves to 184.168.221.13 and there does not seem to exist a valid network path to reach this IP (it stops after 4.53.230.102 which is in Level3). If the problem is permanent I suggest you see directly with your provider.

Comment: GoDaddy's forwarding services don't support HTTPS.

Comment: Right so if I change the nameservers for ultimateedgeapparel.com to match the nameservers of allvolleyball.com, can I manually add redirects at allvolleyball.com to send any requests for https://ultimateedgeapparel.com to https://www.allvolleyball.com/ultimate-edge?

Comment: You'll need to set up DNS records, and get an SSL, but yes.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is answered in the godaddy community: https://www.godaddy.com/community/SSL-And-Security/https-to-https-redirect/td-p/56284

```
1. Create an add-on domain for the old domain
2. Secure old domain and new domain with UCC certificate
3. Set wildcard redirect from old domain to new domain (cpanel -> redirect OR cpanel -> addon domains -> modify addon domain)
```

Comment: I believe this applies if I were also hosting through GoDaddy. The site I'm trying to redirect to is hosted somewhere else.